# Reflected array across a diagonal

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a user input (i) which is an odd number. I want to create an array i times i. So I do the following:

```
reflect = zeros(i, i);
```

Now, I want to produce an array that contains numbers that reflect along the main diagonal.

If i=5, it would look like this:

```
6 4 3 2 1 
1 6 3 2 1
1 2 6 2 1 
1 2 3 6 1  
1 2 3 4 6
```

I can do this using loops but how is this possible using just array funcitons?

Comment: The functions `diag` and `triu` may be useful.

Comment: @nibot Should those two functions be enough or do I need anything else?

Comment: what is the logic behind that matrix? I mean apart from it is `5x5`, how do you decide what elements to place where in that matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a matrix where each row goes from 1 to `i` with `i` rows, then set the upper triangular of the matrix including the diagonal to 0.  Once you do this, take this matrix and rotate it 180 degrees and create another matrix that is the same size as the matrix and an additional matrix with all `i + 1` along the diagonals with zeros being set to everyone else and add the all of the matrices together:

```
i = 5;
M = repmat(1 : i, i, 1);
M(triu(M) ~= 0) = 0;
O = M + (i + 1)*eye(i) + rot90(M, 2);
```

Let's go through each line of code one at a time.  The first line just defines what size matrix you have, which is `i x i`.  Next we create a matrix `M` which goes from 1 to `i` with `i` rows and we can use [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to help us create this matrix by first taking the vector from 1 to `i` and duplicating it `i` times vertically.  Next, we use the [`triu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) function where we extract the upper triangular portion of this matrix including the diagonal, but we will set all of the elements in the upper triangular portion to 0.  We simply compare the upper triangular portion to what is non-zero and use `logical` indexing to help us do this.  This sets the diagonal and the upper triangular portion to 0 leaving the rest intact.

Finally, we take this matrix and add this with the identity matrix with [`eye`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) scaled by `i + 1` and finally to complete the upper half, we simply rotate this same matrix by 180 degrees using [`rot90`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html) to rotate the matrix by 90 degrees, but as we want a 180 degree rotation, we need to rotate by 90 degrees twice, so set the second parmeter `rot90` to 2.

We thus get:

```
>> O

O =

     6     4     3     2     1
     1     6     3     2     1
     1     2     6     2     1
     1     2     3     6     1
     1     2     3     4     6
```